# Getting bad request error while login to my application using office365 api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph REST API for accessing user contacts, calendar, mail data. when I use my office365 email address for login I get following error.  It should show me user permission screen.

> Sign In Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. We received a
>   bad request.

Additional technical information:

> Correlation ID: 8e621ee3-a892-4c7f-baa2-dd20a60594ea Timestamp:
>   2017-04-15 20:18:43Z AADSTS90093: Calling principal cannot consent due
>   to lack of permissions.

Comment: office email which i am using is user and not admin email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What permissions does your application require?

Some permissions require administrator consent in order for you application to use them (maybe you have selected one of those?).

Read more here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/permission_scopes

Comment: Oh yes you are right. In my code I have this scope "User.Read.All" which does require administrator consent.

Comment: I mean you have to click it ^^. From documentation:
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.